# why it does not print the value of fahrenheight and equivalent celsius in reverse order from 300 to -40?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int fahr;
    for(fahr = 300; fahr >= -40; fahr = fahr - 20)
        printf("%3.d %8.d\n ",fahr,(5.0/9.0) * (fahr - 32.0));
}
```

It prints the equivalent values but all wrong. Why is it happening?

Comment: `%8.d` should be `%8.f`, because you're printing float values, not integer ones

Comment: You  mix `int` and `floats` and you use the wrong format specifiers `%d` instead of `%f`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression that converts to Celsius uses constants of type `double` so the expression is of type `double`.  Because you're using the `%d` format specifier with a `double` value, you get undefined behavior.

Change the second format specifier to `%8.f` and you'll get the expected output.  Also, change the first format specifier to `%3.1d` so that when `fahr` is `0` it will print the value instead of just blanks.

```
printf("%3.1d %8.f\n ",fahr,(5.0/9.0) * (fahr - 32.0));
```

Comment: Good catch on the `"%3.1d"`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you trying to use double, where you need to use float. Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
int fahr;
for(fahr = 300; fahr >= -40; fahr = fahr - 20)
    printf("%3.d %8.f\n ",fahr,((fahr - 32) * .5556));
}
```

Comment: This answer's code  does not use `float` anywhere as suggested with "you need to use float".